# Issues on Foursquare API on Android - Keyhash missmatch

Tags: android, oauth, foursquare, android-keystore

I know that this question has been done on a long time, but I spent something around 62 hours reading the questions and answers that I found, the documentation on the Foursquare page and several other sources (as Java website for example) and couldn't find a working answer.
I'm developing a android application in Eclipse, and I've been trying to use the foursquare API to login and make checkins unsucessfully until now.

Here's the problem:

- **I use the libraries: FoursquareOAuthLibrary and EasyFoursquare;**
- **I registered the app on foursquare and couldn't find any guide explaining the purpose of the parameters of the page, other than the obvious ones;**
- **No matter what I put on the "Android Key Hashes" parameter, it aways shows on the app screen the "Android key hash does not match the allowed key hashes specified in the app's settings" error, although it does not log on logcat any error at all;**
- **I've put the hash, the MD5 fingerprint and the SHA1 fingerprint of both keystores (debug.keystore and my own keystore) in the quoted parameter, and nothing worked;**

So, I want to know what hash should I put in that parameter (the **"keyhash"** shown on http://developementsolution.blogspot.in/ Log, the **MD5 fingerprint**, or the **SHA1 fingerprint** that seems to be the only one that looks like the example at https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth/blob/master/README.md).

I also want to know if the code or the libraries could be causing this, and if so, what library I should use.

If possible, I would like to know what the other stuff on the app configuration mean (like "Redirect URI(s)", "Push secret", "Push url" and "Push version" for example).

Answer (score 1):

The SHA1 hash is the one that is required

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to generate your keyhash with this command: `keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore` (Step 3 under ["Setting up your app"](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth/blob/master/README.md#setting-up-your-app))

If you're using the Foursquare Android OAuth library, a redirect URI shouldn't be required, since the library will give you a code. A redirect URI is needed as part of the general [Foursquare OAuth process](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth), but since this library abstracts away this process, the URI isn't required.

The push fields are only required if you're using our [real-time APIs](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime).